# Displaying .gif and continue play during trip to server - asp .net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, animated-gif

I have a button of which I have wired up a clientClick event handler and Click (server) event handler. On clientClick I would like to display an animated gif, and I'd like this to continue playing during the trip to the server. At the moment, gif is displayed momentarily, then it's animation is 'paused' and then page reloaded. I'd like the gif to play right up until the page is reloaded.

As you can probably guess - the whole point of this is to implement an 'egg-timer' feature for the users to be aware of the fact that something's going on.

Thanks a lot,

Dan

Comment: This differs from browser to browser. I think the only way to make this work in all browsers is to submit into an iframe, or use AJax

Comment: you couldn't perhaps use AJAX to load the new page into the existing one, gmail style?

Comment: Well I'll make this easier then and just call it IE for now. IE 10 to be specific.

Comment: Two similar answers then, I'll have a look into this, sounds about right actually.

Comment: The problem is caused at the browser level - once you request another page, the browser stops rendering updates to the display, so your animated GIFs stop showing. I've hit this problem too - I'll be interested in a solution.

Comment: Well it sounds like this iframe thing will do the job. I'm very reluctant to use them usually but this is rather important and I won't need to worry as much about the cross-compatibility issue of browsers as this is all in-house stuff so we determine what browser and version they're using.

Comment: It'd be interesting to see whether a javascript based animation will continue animating once a new page is requested (over normal HTTP). I'm thinking a sprite-based animation could work and be quite efficient...

Comment: I wouldn't know the difference between sprite and javascript based animation to be honest, not normally into web development. I'm gonna have a play around anyway.

Comment: OK, so a normal 'egg-timer' is an animated GIF file, with the animation played and packed by the browser's native rendering engine. A javascript/sprite animation would have all of the frames of the animation in a flat, non-animated image, and then use javascript to adjust the co-ordinates over time to create the animation. I'm going to try it out!

Comment: I had to solve the same problem years ago on IE 6. The solution involved a javascript triggered by the onclick event. The javascript called setTimeout then started the loading of the new page. In the setTimeout callback, a function changed the url of the image to a dummy one, then changed back to the gif. Unfortunately I don't remember the implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Update Panel and from Server side you have to register this `document.all["slowScreenSplash"].style.display = "none";` code.

I have illustrate the the syntax how to register JS from server side if you are using the update panel.

This is batter than the progressbar example.

`<DIV ID="slowScreenSplash" STYLE="position:absolute;z-index:5;top:40%;left:15%;" 
align="center">`
`Please wait whilst your request is being processed...`
`</DIV>`

call this event on button clientclick event.

```
    document.all["slowScreenSplash"].style.display = "none";

string scriptstring = "alert('Welcome');";  
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alertscript", scriptstring, true);
```

Comment: I don't understand how to implement what you've explained to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing asp.net I am guessing youre not implementing a whole lot of JavaScript or Ajax.

There are AJAX plugins for ASP.NET and you could use the refresh container (not 100% sure if that's what it's called) and just hook up to the events in that.

That would probably be the easiest method. You could also read up on jQuery, they provide an AJAX method that is really easy to use. Of course, you will have to provide a method on the server that does the processing and returns the response. Then once you get the response (method for this is easily accessed from the jQuery AJAX method) insert the content into the page and turn the animation off.

If that sounds like a lot just go AJAX in ASP.NET (lookup AJAX Control Toolkit).

Answer (score 0):

I'd split it in to three files - your initial form - a page to process the slow task - a page to render the output of the task.

Put the animated gif at the top of the second page, use Response.Flush to push some html back to the browser (this will render and play the gif). When your finished processing Resoponse.Write a javascript fragment to re-direct the browser to the final page in the process.